# Count posts based on custom select field - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I dont know what im doing wrong here.

CMS = Wordpress

I have a custom post type with 1 custom select field

Custom post type name is loford

Meta key is ptb_select_1

and there are 4 meta values

- select_1
- select_2
- select_3
- select_4

I need to create a shortcode that counts how many posts have select field value "select_1

Here is my code , and it works if I exclude the meta_value,,, but no matter how hard I try , I just cant get it to count based on the select field value

```
function counting_shortcode( $atts ){
    ob_start();

    $args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'loford',
    'meta_key'      => 'ptb_select_1',
    'meta_value'    => 'select_1'
);


      // query
   $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

     // counting the query
  echo $the_query->found_posts;

  $output = ob_get_clean();
  return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'test3', 'counting_shortcode' );
```

For testing purposes , i created text field and that works..

Just not the select field

Can anyone help out please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can do by this way

```
function count_post(){  ?>

   //get value of droup down by javasctipt and pass it into post arg

<select name="select_f" id="select_val" onchange="valueselect(this.value);">
        <option value="">select</option>
        <option value="select_1">select_1</option>
        <option value="select_2">select_2</option>
        <option value="select_3">select_3</option>
        <option value="select_4">select_4</option>
</select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function valueselect(){
        var i = document.getElementById('select_val');
        var p = i.options[i.selectedIndex].value;
        location.href="?p="+p;
    }
    </script>

    <?php
        $post_array = array('post_type'=>'post', 'posts_per_page'=>-1,'meta_key'=>'ptb_select_1','meta_value'=>$_REQUEST['p']);
        $cust_posts = new wp_query($post_array);
        echo "count post-> ".$cust_posts->found_posts;
    ?>
    <?php
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'get_count', 'count_post' );
```